# Customising an ikea kallax 4x4

Tags: tools, powertools, uk, custom-cabinetry, ikea

I'm completely new to diy and wanted some pointers on how to turn an ikea kallax 4x4 to fit into a space.

I would like to sand and repaint the blue pieces.

Questions are:

1. What grit of sandpaper would I need?
2. Do I need a pre-cleaner?
3. What latex paint would be best? recommendations for paint

[image]

Comment: Cut it at 73.5 (the middle) but leave enough on the top and bottom so that the end style (~1") can replace the middle style (~1/2"). So like 75? IDK my units suck, and now that's your problem. Hard part is those cam nuts. Just use a finish nail gun. Partially assemble the half of it. That'll tell you where to cut.

Comment: *I'm completely new to diy and wanted some pointers on how modify some IKEA junk.* ... DON'T.

Comment: Since you're also new to [diy.se], please take the [tour] and look through the [help] on asking questions. You've asked far too many unrelated questions for our format. Yes, they're all related to your project, but cutting and finishing are two different topics. Feel free to [edit] this down to 1 or 2 closely related (as in process, not project), then ask a new question about other _closely_ related parts.

Comment: That said, I will agree with @Mazura, that you're in for a world of hurt attempting to do this. If there are any connectors anywhere in the neighborhood of where you're thinking about cutting, the end result will be... bad...

Comment: @Mazura, your comment is useless without some justification. As it is it's just a random somebody's internet utterance.

Comment: Which one? The one that says how to do it, or the one that says don't do it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not made out of solid wood, and, in particular, the top and bottom pieces may be low quality chipboard with higher quality sections near the edges where the mounting hardware is to be installed.

So this might not be possible at all, and it will look rather weird, as it won't be a 3x4, but something closer to a 2.5 x4

But if you really want to do it, cut 57 cm off of the top and bottom pieces.  Best tool for this would be a table saw, but you can accomplish this with a hand saw or a circular saw if you are very careful. The cuts have to be parallel and square

After that, you'll need to move the mounting hardware from the cut off piece into the new cut off piece. You'll probably need a drill for this. Then you'll reassemble the frame. Now cut the square blue pieces down to size.

If done correctly, you won't need to paint anything.

But probably easier to go to your local second-hand furniture shop and find something that fits better.

Answer (score 1):

The KALLAX furniture can be carefully disassembled, assuming nobody glued it.  You'll want some Ziploc bags... there is A LOT, A LOT of hardware including literally 100 dowels.

Once it's apart, sure... just scuff-sand it (knock the gloss off the prior probably LPU paint or finish) then hit it with an appropriate alkyd primer and enamel. Do it outside, the stuff STINKS.

You can use a latex paint if you really really really want to, but the paint will be very vulnerable to physical damage, i.e. it will scuff up easily / will not wear well, so you'll be back painting it again.

"I don't want to take it apart, that seems like the hard way". Not at all! That has 3 fatal flaws.  First, you have to sand at extremely awkward angles which will affect quality which affects adhesion. I've painted factory-built bookshelves and it's a chore. Take it apart and you're working with completely flat single boards on a workbench, nothing easier.  Second, you're going to have *really bad light* - do it my way and you have ample, uniform bench lighting. Third, the darn thing weighs 75 kilos (150lb). So removing it outside for painting is not practicable and that means not using a high performance alkyd paint.

Answer (score 0):

The upright pieces are solid.  Are the horizontal pieces just held in with metal nub shelf supports?

All you want to do is take it apart and paint it?

Ikea furniture starts flat pack so you can disassemble and paint it.  Those shelves are painted in a high gloss.  You'll need to scuff them for new paint to adhere.  Since you are new to DIY I assume you don't have an HVLP system.

As a new DIY this is just a disassemble and paint project so it isn't outside of what you should attempt.

I'd disassemble and then scuff all surfaces that are going to be visible with either a belt sand or an orbital sander something in the 100 grit.  You are just trying to enhance the bond for new paint not completely remove the old paint.

I'd recommend trying one of the shelves first so you get an idea of the amount of work and make sure you still think it is a good idea.  Buy a can of multiple purpose primer and a can of your finish paint.  Give it one coat of primer and one coat of paint.  See what you think of your work.

Comment: On the KALLAX the horizontals do not move and are pinned in with long dowels. Note that the unit has no back, and all its racking/tramming resistance comes from aforementioned dowels.